# How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in GRUB2?

Tags: scripting, grub2

I want to customize a little my GRUB 2 bootloader, so I'm asking how can I set a variable equal to the output from a command in GRUB2?

I am interested to pass the output of [`date`](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20CLI%20Mode%20Commands.html#date) command to a variable. Moreover, how can I retain only the time or hour in that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Instead to use `date` command, I can use `insmod datehook` module and like this the following environment variables will be accessible: `$YEAR`, `$MONTH`, `$DAY`, `$HOUR`, `$MINUTE`, `$SECOND`, `$WEEKDAY`.

Example: https://askubuntu.com/a/323516/147044

Answer (score 0):

You need [Command Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
now=$(date)
```

Comment: This working in bash, but not when I am using the grub interpreter.

Comment: grub's shell is much more minimal than bash. See this [bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?38893) about capturing command output.

Comment: I know what it is... Hence my question

Comment: if you'll read the link i gave you, there are no plans to include this capability in grub's shell. hence my link to it.

Comment: Ok, you should bring that idea as an answer and if no others answers will appear, I will accept it... but not this answer that is referring at bash.

Comment: there may be some ugly way to script around it with bash's command substitution, but i don't think the effort is worth the time. you might, though. maybe you can invoke the grub command in a bash command sub or something? if you're doing this as a one-off thing, that might be perfectly workable. i'll also note that your question is multi-faceted; first about capturing output, second about making `date` output a specific format of the time or hour.